# Find date ranges in mysql table

Tags: mysql, date

I would like to find all the date ranges in a table that has data and a date column.
A date range will be splitted if no data are in a day.

for example if a table has data between 1-1-2015 until 3-3-2015

and there are no data in days 5-1-2015 and 6-2-2015

then I would like to receive date ranges

```
1-1-2015 until 4-1-2015

6-1-2015 until 5-2-2015

7-2-2015 until 3-3-2015
```

is there a way to do this with a mysql query?

Comment: can do this two ways ( in sql ) : using a calendar table ( if you have one ) or using a cheap simulator of a calendar table with hardcoded cross joins on digits. or you can do it in your application code

Comment: so there is not a query to do the work directly?

Comment: not an inbuilt thing. example below shows how to simulate a calendar table to do this

Comment: So, you have the days, but not the data? It would be much clearer if you provided a concrete example. You have to wonder who upvotes this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**plan**

> - cross join digits together to simulate a calendar table
> - left join calendar to datasource and identify when date not present
> - order over above using sql variables rgn and boundary
> - aggregate over rgn, and boundary to get each region

---

**setup**

```
create table somedates
(
  id integer primary key not null,
  vdate date not null
);

drop view if exists digits_v;
create view digits_v
as
select 0 as n
union all
select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all 
select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
;

insert into somedates
( id, vdate )
select @id := @id + 1 as id, date_add('2015-01-01', interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day) as vdate
from digits_v a2
cross join digits_v a1
cross join digits_v a0
cross join ( select @id := 0 ) params
where date_add('2015-01-01', interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day) <= date('2015-03-03')
and date_add('2015-01-01', interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day) not in
(
  '2015-01-05',
  '2015-02-06'
)
;
```

**query**

```
select rgn, min(boundary) `from`, max(boundary) `to`
from
(
select active.aday, active.present,
@rgn := if(active.present,
           if(@boundary := active.aday, @rgn, @rgn), 
           if(@boundary := null, @rgn + 1, @rgn + 1)) as rgn,
@boundary as boundary
from
(
select date_add('2015-01-01', interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day) as aday,
case when sd.id is not null then true
     else false
end as present
from digits_v a2
cross join digits_v a1
cross join digits_v a0
left join somedates sd
on sd.vdate = date_add('2015-01-01', interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day)
where date_add('2015-01-01', interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day) <= date('2015-03-03')
and date_add('2015-01-01', interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day) >= date('2015-01-01')
) active
cross join ( select @rgn := 0, @boundary := date('2015-01-01') ) params
order by active.aday
) boundaries
group by rgn
having `from` is not null
;
```

**output**

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| rgn |    from    |     to     |
+-----+------------+------------+
|   0 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-04 |
|   1 | 2015-01-06 | 2015-02-05 |
|   2 | 2015-02-07 | 2015-03-03 |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c70c0/1)**

---

**reference**

- [creating mysql calendar table](https://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables)
- [mysql-variable-assignment-how-to-force-assignment-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924353/mysql-variable-assignment-how-to-force-assignment-order)

Comment: One of us has misunderstood the requirement. I think it's you, but the question is so poor, it could just as easily be me.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you have a data set roughly as follows...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(data CHAR(2) NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('AB','2015-01-01'),
('AB','2015-01-02'),
('AB','2015-01-03'),
('AB','2015-01-04'),
(NULL,'2015-01-05'),
('AB','2015-01-06'),
('...etc.''
```

Assuming that's right, then a query could look something like this...

```
SELECT a.date start
     , MIN(c.date) end 
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table b   
    ON b.date = a.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND b.data IS NOT NULL
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table c 
    ON c.date >= a.date 
   AND c.data IS NOT NULL
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table d 
    ON d.date = c.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND d.data IS NOT NULL
 WHERE b.date IS NULL 
   AND c.date IS NOT NULL
   AND d.date IS NULL
   AND a.data IS NOT NULL
 GROUP 
    BY a.date;
```